# Python pandas - particular merge/replacement

Tags: python, pandas

new to pandas operations, I have these two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'], 'id':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'val1':[0,0,0,0,0,0],'val2':[0,0,0,0,0,0],'val3':[0,0,0,0,0,0]})

   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a     0     0     0
1   2    a     0     0     0
2   1    b     0     0     0
3   2    b     0     0     0
4   1    c     0     0     0
5   2    c     0     0     0

subdf = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','b','c'], 'id':[1,1,2],'val1':[0.3,0.4,0.7], 'val2':[4,5,4]}

   id name  val1  val2
0   1    a   0.3     4
1   1    b   0.4     5
2   2    c   0.7     4
```

I would like to obtain as output:

```
   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a   0.3     4     0
1   2    a   0.0     0     0
2   1    b   0.4     5     0
3   2    b   0.0     0     0
4   1    c   0.0     0     0
5   2    c   0.7     4     0
```

But I did not catch example of replacement, just additions of columns/rows from the tutorials I saw !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This takes a couple steps, left [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) on the columns that match, this will create 'x' and 'y' where there are clashes:

```
In [25]:

merged = df.merge(subdf, on=['id', 'name'], how='left')
merged
Out[25]:
   id name  val1_x  val2_x  val3  val1_y  val2_y
0   1    a       0       0     0     0.3       4
1   2    a       0       0     0     NaN     NaN
2   1    b       0       0     0     0.4       5
3   2    b       0       0     0     NaN     NaN
4   1    c       0       0     0     NaN     NaN
5   2    c       0       0     0     0.7       4
In [26]:
# take the values that of interest from the clashes
merged['val1'] = np.max(merged[['val1_x', 'val1_y']], axis=1)
merged['val2'] = np.max(merged[['val2_x', 'val2_y']], axis=1)
merged
Out[26]:
   id name  val1_x  val2_x  val3  val1_y  val2_y  val1  val2
0   1    a       0       0     0     0.3       4   0.3     4
1   2    a       0       0     0     NaN     NaN   0.0     0
2   1    b       0       0     0     0.4       5   0.4     5
3   2    b       0       0     0     NaN     NaN   0.0     0
4   1    c       0       0     0     NaN     NaN   0.0     0
5   2    c       0       0     0     0.7       4   0.7     4
In [27]:
# drop the additional columns
merged = merged.drop(labels=['val1_x', 'val1_y','val2_x', 'val2_y'], axis=1)
merged
Out[27]:
   id name  val3  val1  val2
0   1    a     0   0.3     4
1   2    a     0   0.0     0
2   1    b     0   0.4     5
3   2    b     0   0.0     0
4   1    c     0   0.0     0
5   2    c     0   0.7     4
```

Another method would be to sort both df's on 'id' and 'name' and then call [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas.DataFrame.update):

```
In [30]:

df = df.sort(columns=['id','name'])
subdf = subdf.sort(columns=['id','name'])
df.update(subdf)
df
Out[30]:
   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a   0.3     4     0
2   2    c   0.7     4     0
4   1    c   0.0     0     0
1   1    b   0.4     5     0
3   2    b   0.0     0     0
5   2    c   0.0     0     0
```

Comment: In this case you used `np.max` logic to seperate the column data. In my case there are 17 columns. I want to replace all the data in main df with data coming from left df using left join. I have total 700 rows and need to left join 17 rows. When I try merge with left join , all other rows get NaN data , how can I tackle this problem?

Comment: `sort()` is deprecated. You can use `df.sort_values(by=['id, name'])`

Answer (score 3):

The `sort` function in the second part of the above answer has been deprecated. The code for users using Pandas 0.20+ for achieving the same effect is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrames(usecols=['A', 'B']) # You want to merge TO this
df2 = pd.DataFrames(usecols=['A', 'B']) # You want to merge FROM this 
df1 = df1.sort_values (by=['A', 'B'])
df2 = df2.sort_values (by=['A', 'B'])
df1.update(df2)
```

Refer to: [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Updated** version with `update` method. Inspired by [Nic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928647/3416427)

I managed to it with `concat` but is not as elegant as this one below with `update` and DataFrame are copied, which I believe with bigger tables could result in problems with memory and/or speed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': list('aabbcc'), 'id':[1,2]*3, 'val1':[0]*6,'val2':[0]*6,'val3':[0]*6})

subdf = pd.DataFrame({'name': list('abc'), 'id':[1,1,2],'val1':[0.3,0.4,0.7], 'val2':[4,5,4]})

df.set_index(['name','id'], inplace=True)
df.update(subdf.set_index(['name','id']))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df
```

Result:

```
    name    id  val1    val2    val3
0   a       1   0.3     4.0     0
1   a       2   0.0     0.0     0
2   b       1   0.4     5.0     0
3   b       2   0.0     0.0     0
4   c       1   0.0     0.0     0
5   c       2   0.7     4.0     0
```

Minor drawback is that `pandas.DataFrame.update` changes the dtypes pointed out by [JAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218098/3416427)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is, if all the values of `val1` and `val2` are 0, you can delete the columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'], 'id':[1,2,1,2,1,2], 'val1':[0,0,0,0,0,0],'val2':[0,0,0,0,0,0],'val3':[0,0,0,0,0,0]})
subdf = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','b','c'], 'id':[1,1,2],'val1':[0.3,0.4,0.7], 'val2':[4,5,4]})

print (df)

   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a     0     0     0
1   2    a     0     0     0
2   1    b     0     0     0
3   2    b     0     0     0
4   1    c     0     0     0
5   2    c     0     0     0

print (subdf)

   id name  val1  val2
0   1    a   0.3     4
1   1    b   0.4     5
2   2    c   0.7     4 

df = df.drop(['val1', 'val2'], axis=1)

print (df)

   id name  val3
0   1    a     0
1   2    a     0
2   1    b     0
3   2    b     0
4   1    c     0
5   2    c     0
```

Then do the merge

```
df = df.merge(subdf, on=['id', 'name'], how='left')

print (df)

  name  id  val3  val1  val2
0    a   1     0   0.3   4.0
1    a   2     0   NaN   NaN
2    b   1     0   0.4   5.0
3    b   2     0   NaN   NaN
4    c   1     0   NaN   NaN
5    c   2     0   0.7   4.0
```

And finally use `fillna` to replace the `NaN` values.

```
df['val1'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['val2'].fillna(0, inplace=True)

print (df)

  name  id  val3  val1  val2
0    a   1     0   0.3   4.0
1    a   2     0   0.0   0.0
2    b   1     0   0.4   5.0
3    b   2     0   0.0   0.0
4    c   1     0   0.0   0.0
5    c   2     0   0.7   4.0
```

To sort the columns use

```
column_names = ['id', 'name', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3']
df = df.reindex(columns=column_names)

print (df)

   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a   0.3   4.0     0
1   2    a   0.0   0.0     0
2   1    b   0.4   5.0     0
3   2    b   0.0   0.0     0
4   1    c   0.0   0.0     0
5   2    c   0.7   4.0     0
```

And to parse column to int use

```
df['val2'] = df['val2'].astype(int)

print (df)

   id name  val1  val2  val3
0   1    a   0.3     4     0
1   2    a   0.0     0     0
2   1    b   0.4     5     0
3   2    b   0.0     0     0
4   1    c   0.0     0     0
5   2    c   0.7     4     0
```