# Why does pandas.DataFrame.update change the dtypes of the updated dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to keep the dtypes of the columns as int after the update for obvious reasons. Any ideas why this doesn't work as expected?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'foo'},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 'baz'},
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 'bar'},
])

print 'dtypes before update:\n%s\n%s' % (df1.dtypes, df2.dtypes)

df1.update(df2)

print '\ndtypes after update:\n%s\n%s' % (df1.dtypes, df2.dtypes)
```

The output looks like this:

```
dtypes before update:
a     int64
b     int64
c    object
dtype: object
a     int64
b     int64
c    object
dtype: object

dtypes after update:
a    float64
b    float64
c     object
dtype: object
a     int64
b     int64
c    object
dtype: object
```

Thanks to anyone that has some advise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4094 I think your only option currently is calling `astype(int)` after the update.

Comment: this bug has been open for 10 years and is still a bug. Unreal

Answer (score 0):

in pure pandas you can try:

```py
# get shp schema
schema = dbf_df.dtypes

# Update the dbf dataframe with values from the xlsx dataframe
dbf_df.update(xlsx_df)

# fix d_types
dbf_df = dbf_df.astype(schema)
```

in geopandas if you update shp:

```
input_gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_path)
# original schema
with fiona.open(shp_path) as src:
    # Extract the schema
    schema = src.schema

# perform update

input_gdf.to_file('res_path', schema=schema)
```

Fiona schema:
 [https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#keeping-schemas-simple:~:text=WILDRNP020%27%3A%20%27int%3A10%27%7D%7D-,1.4.1%20Keeping%20Schemas%20Simple,-%EF%83%81](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#keeping-schemas-simple:%7E:text=WILDRNP020%27%3A%20%27int%3A10%27%7D%7D-,1.4.1%20Keeping%20Schemas%20Simple,-%EF%83%81)