# Python Pandas update a dataframe value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in python. I want to update rows in first dataframe using  matching values from another dataframe. Second dataframe serves as an override.

Here is an example with same data and code:

DataFrame 1 :

[image]

DataFrame 2:

[image]

I want to update update dataframe 1 based on matching code and name. In this example Dataframe 1 should be updated as below:

[image]

Note : Row with Code =2 and Name= Company2 is updated with value 1000 (coming from Dataframe 2)

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
         'Code': [1, 2, 3],
         'Name': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3'],
         'Value': [200, 300, 400],

    }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Code','Name','Value'])

data2 = {
         'Code': [2],
         'Name': ['Company2'],
         'Value': [1000],
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns= ['Code','Name','Value'])
```

Any pointers or hints?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can using `concat` + `drop_duplicates` which updates the common rows and adds the new rows in df2

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['Code','Name'],keep='last').sort_values('Code')
Out[1280]: 
   Code      Name  Value
0     1  Company1    200
0     2  Company2   1000
2     3  Company3    400
```

Update due to below comments

```
df1.set_index(['Code', 'Name'], inplace=True)

df1.update(df2.set_index(['Code', 'Name']))

df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this solution not only updates the entries frame dataframe1 but also adds new entries from dataframe2 which were not present in dataframe1 before.

Comment: It also blows up the memory as it has to make a duplicate of both dataframes before dropping the duplicates.

Answer (score 85):

Using DataFrame.update, which aligns on indices (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
>>> df1.set_index('Code', inplace=True)
>>> df1.update(df2.set_index('Code'))
>>> df1.reset_index()  # to recover the initial structure

   Code      Name   Value
0     1  Company1   200.0
1     2  Company2  1000.0
2     3  Company3   400.0
```

Comment: This seems to be the most ideal solution among all... but Nic, can you help me with one thing?... what if df1 and df2 had 5 columns in each, but I wanted to update only the "Value" column, and not the rest of them(above code updates all columns pertaining to that "index")... is that possible pls? Kindly help ...

Comment: Why is `Value` column converted to `float`?

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. You can also expand this to multiple lookup columns: `df1.set_index(['Code', 'Name'], inplace=True)` and updates multiple measure columns in case you have e.g. Value, Sales, etc.

Answer (score 15):

You can merge the data first and then use numpy.where, [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)'s how to use `numpy.where`

```
updated = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=['Code', 'Name'], suffixes=('', '_new'))
updated['Value'] = np.where(pd.notnull(updated['Value_new']), updated['Value_new'], updated['Value'])
updated.drop('Value_new', axis=1, inplace=True)

   Code      Name   Value
0     1  Company1   200.0
1     2  Company2  1000.0
2     3  Company3   400.0
```

Comment: Thanks. So Left join and then update 'Value' field with 'Value_new'  for non NaN rows.

Answer (score 14):

There is a **update** function available

example:

```
df1.update(df2)
```

for more info:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Comment: older same and better answer exists already

Comment: It would be required to set_index first to use update reliably.

Answer (score 10):

You can align indices and then use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
res = df2.set_index(['Code', 'Name'])\
         .combine_first(df1.set_index(['Code', 'Name']))\
         .reset_index()

print(res)

#    Code      Name   Value
# 0     1  Company1   200.0
# 1     2  Company2  1000.0
# 2     3  Company3   400.0
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer, cause: Combine two DataFrame objects by filling null values in one DataFrame with non-null values from other DataFrame. The row and column indexes of the resulting DataFrame will be the union of the two.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html   @safiqul islam mentioned below the update function, which seeems to work.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Comment: @CorinaRosa Can you give a counter-example?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `company` and `code` are redundant identifiers, you can also do

```
import pandas as pd
vdic = pd.Series(df2.Value.values, index=df2.Name).to_dict()

df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(vdic.keys()), 'Value'] = df1.loc[df1.Name.isin(vdic.keys()), 'Name'].map(vdic)

#   Code      Name  Value
#0     1  Company1    200
#1     2  Company2   1000
#2     3  Company3    400
```

Answer (score 4):

There's something I often do.

I merge 'left' first:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'Code')
```

Pandas will create columns with extension '_x' (for your left dataframe) and
'_y' (for your right dataframe)

You want the ones that came from the right. So just remove any columns with '_x' and rename '_y':

```
for col in df_merged.columns:
    if '_x' in col:
        df_merged .drop(columns = col, inplace = True)
    if '_y' in col:
        new_name = col.strip('_y')
        df_merged .rename(columns = {col : new_name }, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) on the result of left-joining `df1` and `df2`

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['Code', 'Name'], how='left')
df1.Value = merged.Value_y.where(~merged.Value_y.isnull(), df1.Value)
>>> df1
    Code    Name    Value
0   1   Company1    200.0
1   2   Company2    1000.0
2   3   Company3    400.0
```

You can change the line to

```
df1.Value = merged.Value_y.where(~merged.Value_y.isnull(), df1.Value).astype(int)
```

in order to return the value to be an integer.

Comment: Why is it adding .0 to the value ? (Not a big deal, but just curious)

Comment: @ProgSky It is because the type changed. I updated the answer to show how to return it to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Append the dataset
2. Drop the duplicate by `code`
3. Sort the values

```
combined_df = combined_df.append(df2).drop_duplicates(['Code'],keep='last').sort_values('Code')
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for my particular example, which I think is rooted in the dtype of my columns, but I eventually came to this solution

```
indexes = df1.loc[df1.Code.isin(df2.Code.values)].index
df1.at[indexes,'Value'] = df2['Value'].values
```