# How to recover the initial structure after update one Python pandas dataframe with another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the original post:
[Python Pandas update a dataframe value from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928463/python-pandas-update-a-dataframe-value-from-another-dataframe)

df1 and df2 have the same data structure.

The original column order:
assignee id issuetype key

The problem is that after runing the following code:

```
df1.set_index('key',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('key'))
df1.reset_index()
```

The column order of df1 changed to this:

key assignee id issuetype

How can I recover the initial structure after update one dataframe with another dataframe? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change order by original columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
cols = df1.columns
df1.set_index('key',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('key'))
df1 = df1.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df1)
```

Comment: I tired it, it didn't work. The "Key" is still the first column.

Comment: @Ming - Sorry, answer was edited. `cols` is necessary use for variable

Comment: it didn't work on my side, here is my code:  df1=pd.read_csv("update_1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("update_2.csv")


cols = df1.columns
df1.set_index('key',inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('key'))
df1.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1)

Comment: @Ming - Is assigned back output? Like `df1 = df1.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1)` and then `print (df1)` ? Answer was edited.

Comment: Yes, the printed out structure is not recovered.

Comment: @Ming - What is `print (df1.columns)`  before `df1 = df1.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1)`?

Comment: df1 = df1.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1) worked. but it added new blank column as the firts column.  the new structure is this : "Blank Column" Unnamed:0 assignee id issuetype key

Comment: @Ming - So in original data is `Blank Column" Unnamed: 0` ? What is `print (cols)` ?

Comment: the printed out  content of original df1 and updated df1 are the same, but if you compare the CSV files, the output csv file (df1.to_csv(r'output.csv'))has a blank first column.

Comment: @Ming - Do you use `df1.to_csv(file, index=False)` ?

Comment: index=False works, the index column is gone. Thank you very much, jezrael !

Comment: another question if df1 and df2 have the same data structure, I want to update df1 with df2 when "key"  values are matched and also add the record from df2 when its key value is not matched with df1, what kind of function should I use. Thanks.

Comment: @Ming - Can you create new question with sample data `df1, df2` and expected output?