# How do you combine two dataframes with timestamp indexes, overwriting the first and not duplicating rows?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, both with timestamp indexes. They have similar columns (the second dataframe lacks two columns). The second dataframe is also regularly re-created every second with new data, from some API. How can I continuously update the first dataframe with the information from the second (or the API)?

First dataframe looks like this:

```
                           Open        High  ...          MA        EMA
2021-04-29 09:31:00  583.473999  583.473999  ...         NaN        NaN
2021-04-29 09:32:00  584.304932  585.394850  ...  584.349534 583.983949
```

Second one looks like this:

```
                        Open     High      Low    Close
2021-04-29 09:33:00  578.107  579.412  577.942  579.251
```

I've already tried `join`, `append`, `concat`, `combine_first`, and `update`, all wrapped in some asyncio loop, with no success on any of them. They either don't update the first dataframe at all, or it doesn't overwrite the same index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`pd.concat(df1, df2)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the dataframes, then run [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with the argument `keep='last'`, as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928776/13758710)

Comment: [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) ignores indexes and only has an option to check for columns. Is there any way to do this without having to copy the index to a column?

Comment: Try this: after concatenating, set ```df1 = df1[~df1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]```.

Comment: That results in the dataframe keeping the first value of that index, which isn't ideal since the point of the concat/append was to overwrite with the most up-to-date data. I've, uhh, decided to just copy the index to a column and use your first solution because settling is the key to happiness.

Comment: Haha, that's the spirit! I'm sorry it wasn't more plug-and-play. Have a nice day!