# Combining rows of two Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've been looking through [`the documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) and [`Pandas Merging 101`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/14185615), but help was nowhere to be found.

### Suppose I have two Dataframes as follows

```
>>> df

    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple      0           0
1   Banana      0           0
2  Samsung      0           0
3   Orange      0           0
```

```
>>> df2

    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple     14        0.74
1  Samsung      5        0.26
```

### And I want to merge the two Dataframes to produce the following result

```
>>> result

    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple     14        0.74
1   Banana      0           0
2  Samsung      5        0.26
3   Orange      0           0
```

Keep in mind that `df2` is always a subset of `df`.

In other words, every **Values** in `df2` will be guaranteed to present in the **Values** of `df`.

### Here is what I have so far

```
result = df.merge(df2, on='Values', how='left')
```

```
>>> result

    Values  Count_x  Percentage_x  Count_y  Percentage_y
0    Apple        0             0     14.0          0.74
1   Banana        0             0      NaN           NaN
2  Samsung        0             0      5.0          0.26
3   Orange        0             0      NaN           NaN
```

But the result is kind of disappointing.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas update a dataframe value from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928463/python-pandas-update-a-dataframe-value-from-another-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a `pd.concat` followed by a `.drop_duplicates()`

```
>>> df1
    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple      0           0
1   Banana      0           0
2  Samsung      0           0
3   Orange      0           0
>>> df2
    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple     14        0.74
1  Samsung      5        0.26
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(subset='Values', keep='last')
    Values  Count  Percentage
1   Banana      0        0.00
3   Orange      0        0.00
0    Apple     14        0.74
1  Samsung      5        0.26
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `update`. After setting the index, just update the value in df1 with new values:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Values')
df1 = df1.update(df2.set_index('Values')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- set the index in *df* to *Values* and save the result
  in a temporary DataFrame,
- **update** it with *df2* with the index set also to *Values*
  (*update* is performed in place),
- reset the index to convert *Values* to a regular column,
- maybe save this result back under *df*.

The code to do it is:

```
wrk = df.set_index('Values')
wrk.update(df2.set_index('Values'))
df = wrk.reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
    Values  Count  Percentage
0    Apple   14.0        0.74
1   Banana    0.0        0.00
2  Samsung    5.0        0.26
3   Orange    0.0        0.00
```