# Dataframe compare, combine and merge for rectangular meshgrid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, contourf

I have two dataframes shown below:

df_1 =

```
   Lon Lat  N
0   2   1   1
1   2   2   3
2   2   3   1
3   3   2   2
```

and

df_2 =

```
    Lon Lat N
0   1.0 1.0 NaN
1   2.0 1.0 NaN
2   3.0 1.0 NaN
3   4.0 1.0 NaN
4   1.0 2.0 NaN
5   2.0 2.0 NaN
6   3.0 2.0 NaN
7   4.0 2.0 NaN
8   1.0 3.0 NaN
9   2.0 3.0 NaN
10  3.0 3.0 NaN
11  4.0 3.0 NaN
```

What I want to do is to compare these two dfs and merge them according to `Lon` and `Lat`. That is to say `NaN` in df_2 will be covered with values in df_1 if the corresponding `Lon` and `Lat` are identical. The ideal output should be as:

```
    Lon Lat N
0   1.0 1.0 NaN
1   2.0 1.0 1
2   3.0 1.0 NaN
3   4.0 1.0 NaN
4   1.0 2.0 NaN
5   2.0 2.0 3
6   3.0 2.0 2
7   4.0 2.0 NaN
8   1.0 3.0 NaN
9   2.0 3.0 1
10  3.0 3.0 NaN
11  4.0 3.0 NaN
```

The reason I want to do this is df_1's coordinates `Lat` and `Lon` are non-rectangular or unstructured grid, and I need to fill some `NaN` values so as to get a rectangular meshgrid and make `contourf` applicable. It would be highly appreciated if you can provide better ways to make the contour plot.

I have tried `df_2.combine_first(df_1)`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_2.drop(columns = 'N').merge(df_1, on = ['Lon', 'Lat'], how = 'left')

    Lon  Lat    N
0   1.0  1.0  NaN
1   2.0  1.0  1.0
2   3.0  1.0  NaN
3   4.0  1.0  NaN
4   1.0  2.0  NaN
5   2.0  2.0  3.0
6   3.0  2.0  2.0
7   4.0  2.0  NaN
8   1.0  3.0  NaN
9   2.0  3.0  1.0
10  3.0  3.0  NaN
11  4.0  3.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want. I give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you first create the df_2 with all needed values you can update it with the second DataFrame by using [pandas.DataFrame.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html?highlight=update#pandas.DataFrame.update).

For this you need to first set the the correct index by using [pandas.DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index#pandas.DataFrame.set_index).

Have a look at [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928463/python-pandas-update-a-dataframe-value-from-another-dataframe) for more information.