# How to replace some rows df1 (outdated) with all rows of df2 (update of df1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

by using pandas, I'd like to find a way to replace some rows of df1 (outdated) with all rows of df2 (update of df1) based on column values (Date) + new possible rows df2 (part of the update) containing new dates under Date column.

Assumptions:
Essentially, I'm talking about an incremental update of a dataframe that will happen periodically. E.g.:

- week0=df1
- week1: df1+df2(update)=df3
- week2: df3+df4(update)=df5
- week3: df5+df6(update)=df7

The columns are equal on both dataframes: date, name, surname, vendor, quantity

Any suggestion?

Comment: Set the merging key as index and use `combine_first`

Comment: Can you merge both lists and then delete duplicates?  pd.drop_duplicates. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas update a dataframe value from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928463/python-pandas-update-a-dataframe-value-from-another-dataframe)