# How to substitute string values in one dataframe based on another "corrections" dataframe without for loop or merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two DataFrames, an "original" and "correction" dataframe such that

```
orig = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B'],'Code':['9q8','7k2']})

Name Code
A    9q8
B    7k2

corr = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A',],'Code':['9R8',]})
Name Code
A    9R8
```

How can I assign `orig['Code']=corr['Code']` wherever `orig['Name']==corr['Name]` without merging or iterating through each correction in corr and then each original in orig? The final result should look like this:

```
Name Code
A    9R8
B    7k2
```

I did see another [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762902/python-pandas-particular-merge-replacement) similar to my current question, but in that example the answer used a merge and then a selection mechanism to get rid of the old rows that are no longer desired. However, I have no such selection mechanism.

For example, if I merge orig and corr, I get:

```
out = pd.merge(orig,corr,on='Name',how='outer')
Name Code
A    9q8
A    9R8
B    7k2
```

Which, If I'm looking at thousands of rows, leaves me no way to know which of     `A 9q8` and `A 9R8` was the substitution and which wasn't. I can't use an indicator column to tell substitutions from non-substitutions, because deleting all entries that are "left-only" would also remove the entry `B 7k2`.

Comment: `orig.update(corr)`

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I tried this and it works! But how? From the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) there aren't any examples of column-based substitution, only index-based. Then again, although there aren't examples, it does say "only values at matching index/*column* labels are updated" How can I know when `.update()` will update based on matching  column values and when it will update based on matching index values? It doesn't look like there's an argument you can pass to `.update()` that allows you to chose index/column

Comment: `update()` "Aligns on indices" and updates matching columns in the left dataframe with data from the right

Comment: I see, so `.update()` replaces the entries in the left table with those in the right wherever the indices match, `index_left==index_right`, but only for columns that are in both the left table and the right table, `colName_left == colName_right`. And, if I want, I can change the index I'm matching on to some other arbitrary column with `.set_index()`.

Comment: yes that is correct. You can also specify the columns to update if the names do not match. Data will be updated based on the index: `df1['col1'].update(df2['col2'])` this will update `df1['col1']` with the data from `df2['col2']` where the indices match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
orig.set_index('Name',inplace=True)
orig.update(corr.set_index('Name'))

orig.reset_index(inplace=True)
orig
Out[164]: 
  Name Code
0    A  9R8
1    B  7k2
```