# Setting value of columns in one dataframe to another dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` :-

| id | Group | Family | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tri23_1 | Laavin | A |
| 2 | hsgç_T2 | Grendy | B |
| 3 | bbbj-1Y_jn | Fantol | C |
| 4 | hsgç_T2 | Gondow | D |

and have a dataframe `df2` :-

| id | Group | Family | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tri | Brendy | B |
| 2 | hsgç_T2 | Fantol | A |
| 5 | bbbj-1Y_jn | Fantol | E |
| 6 | hsgç_T3 | Gondow | D |

For `id` in `df1` that are present in `df2`,I want to set `Group` ,`Family`,`Bonus` columns alone of `df2` in `df1`.
Expected `df1`:-

| id | Group | Family | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tri | Brendy | B |
| 2 | hsgç_T2 | Fantol | A |
| 3 | bbbj-1Y_jn | Fantol | C |
| 4 | hsgç_T2 | Gondow | D |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas - particular merge/replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762902/python-pandas-particular-merge-replacement)

Comment: @VladimirFokowno it does not. the `update` method updates all columns, but I specifically want only a few columns be updated

Comment: Can `id` be set as an index? Or it must be a column?

Comment: it must be a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
shared_columns = ['Group', 'Family', 'Bonus']
```

**One-liner:**

```py
df1.update(df1.set_index('id')[shared_columns]
              .align(df2.set_index('id'), join='left')[1]
              .set_axis(df1.index, axis=0))
```

---

My original solution:

```py
replacements = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left')
                  .iloc[:, -len(shared_columns):])
replacements.columns = shared_columns

df1.update(replacements)
```

**Example:**

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,  1, 0.1, 1], 
                    [2,  2, 0.2, 2], 
                    [3,  3, 0.3, 3]], 
                   columns=['id', 'Group', 'Family', 'Bonus'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3,  30, 300, 3], 
                    [1,  10, 100, 1], 
                    [4,  40, 400, 4]], 
                   columns=['id', 'Group', 'Family', 'Bonus'])
```

`df1`:

```py
   id  Group  Family  Bonus
0   1      1     0.1      1
1   2      2     0.2      2
2   3      3     0.3      3
```

`df2`:

```py
   id  Group  Family  Bonus
0   3     30     300      3
1   1     10     100      1
2   4     40     400      4
```

`pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left'`
performs a left-merge, on the column `id`:

```py
   id  Group_x  Family_x  Bonus_x  Group_y  Family_y  Bonus_y
0   1        1       0.1        1     10.0     100.0      1.0
1   2        2       0.2        2      NaN       NaN      NaN
2   3        3       0.3        3     30.0     300.0      3.0
```

`replacements` (after selecting the last columns, and renaming them):

```py
   Group  Family  Bonus
0   10.0   100.0    1.0
1    NaN     NaN    NaN
2   30.0   300.0    3.0
```

Resulting `df1`:

```py
   id  Group  Family  Bonus
0   1   10.0   100.0    1.0
1   2    2.0     0.2    2.0
2   3   30.0   300.0    3.0
```

---

**Another way to select the right columns after merging:**

By default, [.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) uses `suffixes=('_x', '_y')`. So to select the columns of the right data frame, we can append `'_y'` to each its column name:

```py
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left')
right_colnames = [colname + '_y' for colname in shared_columns]
replacements = merged[right_colnames]
```

```py
   Group_y  Family_y  Bonus_y
0     10.0     100.0      1.0
1      NaN       NaN      NaN
2     30.0     300.0      3.0
```

---

Another solution:

```py
temp_df = df1.reset_index().set_index('id')
temp_df.update(df2.set_index('id')[shared_columns])
df1 = temp_df.reset_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(None, axis=0)
```

Comment: what is I do not have these columns in the end? how can i modify `-len`

Comment: @Scope, added a way to do that

Comment: Just found out about the [`.align()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) method - it can be used instead or mergind and then selecting

Comment: oh how do we do it using `align`

Comment: @Scope, added this method to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: where does it actually subset the columns/variables for align?

Answer (score 0):

if setting index on DF is acceptable, then this is one way to accomplish it. Using update

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df
```

```
    Group       Family  Bonus
id          
1   tri         Brendy  B
2   hsgç_T2     Fantol  A
3   bbbj-1Y_jn  Fantol  C
4   hsgç_T2     Gondow  D
```